# Can minifying JS cause issues with embedding external JS into my website? If so, how do I work around this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I am currently building our company's website using WordPress and have run into some issues embedding a snippet of html which points to a menu of sorts and renders that menu as a widget on our website (snippet below):

```
<div id="leafly-menu">
</div>

<div style="text-align:center;">
    Visit our profile on <a href="https://www.leafly.com/dispensary- 
    info/happy-hemp">Leafly</a>
</div>

<script 
        src="https://www.leafly.com/public/global/js/dispensarymana
        ger/embed.js"> 
</script>

<script>
    var pymParent = pym.Parent('leafly-menu', 
    'https://www.leafly.com/embed/menu2/happy-hemp', {});
</script>
```

This worked for a while. When visiting the website as anyone normally would, the menu rendered and operated as it should have. However, since then I've had more time to build a more fleshed-out website/design and now this snippet no longer works. This snippet of HTML is the snippet of HTML provided by Leafly and thus I have no control over the actual JS or HTML of the snippet myself nor do I have access to change any parameters about how my website is fetching the JS file from their end.

Here's a breakdown of some of the more notworthy things being used to build the website:

- CMS: WordPress
- Noteworthy Plugins: Elementor PRO (Page builder) | Premium Addons PRO (Elementor 
  extension)
- Performance Plugins: WP Rocket (Caching & Performance) | Imagify (WP Rocket 
  Extension/Media File Compression) | Cloudflare (CDN; *Cache policy is integrated 
  with and controlled by WP Rocket)

The only true changes that I've made to the website outside of aesthetics is attempting to pay mind to optimization and performance. In lieu of that, I opted to purchase WP Rocket; a plug-in for WordPress sites which helps with controlling cache policies among a list of other offered features. It was around this time that I noticed that the snippet stopped working.

Keeping in mind that WP Rocket integrates with and controls the cache policy of my Cloudflare CDN, WP Rocket also allows the ability to minify JS, HTML, and CSS. In doing some research, I opted to use the following features of WP Rocket:

- HTML Minification
- Combine Google Fonts
- CSS Minification
- JS Minification (excluding any JS at this path:
  www.leafly.com/public/global/js/dispensarymanager/embed.js)
- Defer JS
- Safemode for JQuery
- Cache Preloading (Preloads automatically every 24hrs)

Now, I've tried everything I thought to personally check for myself. In my cache policy, I've excluded anything and everything coming from "leafly.com/", I've tried whitelisting "leafly.com/" in my Cloudflare firewall rules & exceptions. I've tried restructuring the HTML in the snippet provided by Leafly; etc. Anything I could think of that might cause issues rendering the JS of the Leafly embed, I tried to disable. Still, no cigar.

So then that leads to me asking:

- what would cause an HTML embed from a 3rd party-- which was once
  working, to all of the sudden stop working/rendering correctly?
- would minifying my JS or CSS cause or be the source of this issue?

Guys (and gals), I'm drawing a blank here. I just can't figure the damn thing out and would love some suggestions regarding troubleshooting and solutions.

Here is how the HTML is served to the end-user when visiting the site in the area where the menu should be located.

```
<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-9bb0fdd elementor-widget 
elementor-widget-global elementor-global-1233 elementor-widget-html" 
data-id="9bb0fdd" data-element_type="widget" data- 
widget_type="html.default">

        <div class="elementor-widget-container">

                <div id="leafly-menu">

                        <div style="text-align:center;">

                            Visit our profile on 
                                <a href="https://www.leafly.com/dispensary- 
                                info/happy-hemp">
                                    Leafly
                                </a>
                        </div>

                        <script src=
                            "//www.leafly.com/public/global/js/
                            dispensarymanager/embed.js" defer="">
                        </script> 

                        <script>
                            var pymParent = pym.Parent('leafly-menu', 
                            'https://www.leafly.com/embed/menu2/happy- 
                            hemp', {});
                        </script> 
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Here is a link comparing what it should render out to look like vs. what it truly renders out to be now:

- What it should render to be: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrOS0.jpg
- How it actually renders: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gDkT.jpg

Here is a link to the global JS file as provided by Leafly:

- https://www.leafly.com/public/global/js/dispensarymanager/embed.js

The only hint I've been able to glean is through inspecting the div container on the webpage itself; in which toward the bottom of the dev console I get a yellow triangle with an exclamation point-- which reads:

- JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1 content.min.js:2
  [Deprecation] Element.createShadowRoot is deprecated and will be
  removed in M73, around March 2019. Please use Element.attachShadow
  instead. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/4507242028072960
  for more details.

If anyone has any ideas of the best way to troubleshoot or fix this issue, please help a brother out:P

Thanks!

Comment: Look at the line -> `var pymParent =`, can you see how the url has now been spitted out onto 2 lines, this will break your JS.  So I would say it's the HTML minification that's broken, it looks like it's breaking lines on the `-`

Comment: I'm sorry I did that so that way the code would appear organized in this post. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: WpRocket suggests disabling all features, and then enable 1 at a time to find what feature breaks your site.  More info here -> https://docs.wp-rocket.me/article/106-my-site-is-broken